# How does a UIConfigurationColorTransformer work?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios14

[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiconfigurationcolortransformer) says:

> Because color transformers can use the same base input color to produce a number of variants of that color, you can create different appearances for different states of your views.

Okay. I would like to try using the new iOS 14 `backgroundConfiguration` architecture instead of setting the cell's `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView`. I want my UITableViewCell to have a blue background normally but a gray background when selected. So, in my `cellForRowAt` implementation:

```
var b = UIBackgroundConfiguration.listPlainCell()
b.backgroundColor = .blue
cell.backgroundConfiguration = b
```

So far, so good; the cell is blue. But what about the gray? This is where I expect the color transformer to come in:

```
var b = UIBackgroundConfiguration.listPlainCell()
b.backgroundColor = .blue
b.backgroundColorTransformer = // what?
cell.backgroundConfiguration = b
```

The color transformer is a function that takes a color and returns a color. And I can see by logging that the color transformer function is actually called every time the cell's state changed. But the function itself doesn't take a state. It has no access to the cell's state. So how do I, as Apple claims, "create different appearances for different states"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As near as I can tell, there are two parts to the answer:

- You are configuring the background configuration in `cellForRowAt`, so you have a reference to the cell and therefore to its cell configuration state.
- If you set the background configuration's `backgroundColor` explicitly, you can't set it through the `backgroundColorTransformer`. It's one or the other. (That feels buggy to me, but whatever.)

So, the following does what I want:

```
var b = UIBackgroundConfiguration.listPlainCell()
b.backgroundColorTransformer = UIConfigurationColorTransformer { [weak cell] c in
    if let state = cell?.configurationState {
        if state.isSelected || state.isHighlighted {
            return .gray
        }
    }
    return .blue
}
cell.backgroundConfiguration = b
```

Comment: Just highlighting that setting "backgroundColor" directly on the UIBackgroundConfiguration will break the UIConfigurationColorTransformer.